# matching 2 dfs on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, match

I am trying to get the corresponding value of df1 from df2 based on 2 conditions.
here are the 2 dfs.
df1:

```
    name value1
0   abc  3      
1   cde  1      
2   cde  4      
3   ijk  6
```

df2:

```
    name value1 value2
0   abc  3      5
1   cde  3      5
2   cde  1      1
3   ijk  2      3
```

I want to get in df1 the df2.value2 for which the name matches and for which `df1.value1.between(df2.value1, df2.value2)` is verified

I have tried:

```
df1['value2'] = df2[(df2['name']==df1['name'])(df1['value1'].between(df2['value1']., df2['value2']))]['value2']
```

but without luck.. do you guys have any suggestion?

here you see my expected output on df1:

```
    name value1 value2
0   abc  3      5
1   cde  1      1
2   cde  4      5
3   ijk  6      nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `merge` both columns together and then filter by `between`, if necessary missing values for non matched values add `merge` with left join:

```
print (df1)
  name  value1  col
0  abc       3    1
1  cde       1    5
2  cde       4    7
3  ijk       6    3


df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))

df = df[df.value1.between(df.value1_, df.value2)]
df = df1.merge(df[df2.columns], how='left')
print (df)
  name  value1  col  value2
0  abc       3   10     5.0
1  cde       1   50     1.0
2  cde       4   70     5.0
3  ijk       6   30     NaN
```

Comment: if I merge on name there could be more than one match, no? how can it work?

Comment: @lorenzo - It working `merge` create all combination by `name` and then filtered by `between`.

Comment: @lorenzo - And get all match. Do you need only first?

Comment: @lorenzo - Try change in sample data for `df2` - `2;cde;1;3
`

Comment: it seems that it will lose the content of the other columns when creating the combinations

Comment: @lorenzo - If remove last `df = df1.merge(df[df2.columns], how='left')` it working?

Comment: I have to remove the one that doesn't match with between. it's a double match, both name plus value in range

Comment: @lorenzo - Is possible change sample data with this? Thanks.

Comment: the data sample I provide presents already this issue: you would match both (1   cde  3      5) and (2   cde  1      1) while only one match with each of df1 I made a correction, please see

Comment: I have the feeling you need to loop in df2 to find the matching one, but not sure how to do it

Comment: @lorenzo - How looks expected output?

Comment: @lorenzo - For me working nice. Btw, if df2 - `1   cde  3      5` is `1   cde  1      5` what is expected output?

Comment: no, that's overlap of values would not happen in the data, so no problem. checking again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191066/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-jezrael).

Comment: hi Jezrael, I believe you are right, it seems to always find the match. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['value2'] =np.where(df1.value1.between(df2.value1, df2.value2), df2['value2'], np.nan)
```

Comment: hi Loochie, this seem to return ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects